# ASP.NET Hyperlink control not render href on ascx webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a Hyperlink control on an .ascx that looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hDocument" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="Delegate Approval" Target="_blank" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

However, when I navigate to my SharePoint page where this URL is supposed to be displayed, the hyperlink is not clickable and there is no href in the HTML anchor tag () like so:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl40_g_65ace0cb_fdf4_4d40_ae31_9736b2d39022_gvLevel1Approvals_ctl02_hDocument" target="_blank">Delegate Approval</a>
```

I place a normal HTML anchor under the Hyperlink control and that one works fine.  I have no idea why the Hyperlink control doesn't produce a href attribute when it renders.

Edit:

Here's the original code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hDocument" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

code behind

```
HyperLink hDocument = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hDocument");
hDocument.Text = "Delegate Approval";
hDocument.NavigateUrl = // builiding URL here;
hDocument.Target = "_blank";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So our situation with the  was it would work only intermittently but 95% of the time it didn't work.  Everything else worked fine: building the URL in the code behind, setting the link text, everything.  We could not figure out why the href would not show up on the page on the client browser.  In the end I eventually switched to using a regular HTML anchor tag  and added in the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace to find the anchor and modify that in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could solve it only by setting the **NavigateUrl** in **Code Behind** (in **Page_Load**).

Comment: Our original code sets the NavigateUrl in the code behind and it was not working.  I switched it to the .ascx page to be more basic to see if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In VB.net

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("href", "http://www.clarin.com")
```

In my situation Visual Studio converted ASPX to HTML5.
When VS converts the document to HTML - if you perform some debugging - you will see:

```
<a NavigateURL="someurl" blablabla
```

but `NavigateURL` is not found in HTML.

You MUST replace the attribute `NavigateURL` with `href`.

I do not know if this is a compiler error, but it was the only reasonable solution I could find.